# Spring 3 Web MVC with JMX client and remote service not running

Tags: java, spring

The problem is relatively simple:

I have a web based application, that, among other things, needs to check for status of a remote service. This remote service has JMX based mbeans exposed. However, the remote service might be not running all the time. What I need is:

1. Setup Spring to connect to remote JMX server
2. When the remote is not running, present this information in the web ui

The problem with this is that if I setup the JMX client bean in springContext.xml and the service is not running, the webapp won't even start with exceptions like ConnectionRefused and so on.

So the question is: is there a way I can tell spring to ignore the fact that it cannot connect to remote mbean server and try it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the `MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean`?  Set the `connectOnStartup` property to `false`.

Comment: Ok, this works, thank you, but this results in a follow up problem. When the remote shuts down sometime after the connection was established and then resumes it's operation, I would need of course to reconnect to it. Can this be done? From what I understand, this kind of instrumentation should be left to Java JMX itself, but I am not sure

Comment: I think in this case you're better off using the JMX APIs directly instead of using Spring's wrapper.  Check out the source for  MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean.connect() to see how they are doing it.

Comment: Well, probably subclassing the client or something should work, thanks anyway